# Russian self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Nice for beginners

Answer (score 3):

["Horse has gypsy in its teeth" - what does it exactly mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/797/is-this-english-translation-correct)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Title is too general, apart from that it's not a bad question at all, for me.

Comment: A good enough question, on-topic.

Comment: Question is valid and on-topic. But I think someone should propose more specific title

Answer (score 2):

[не хватает ... рубля/рублей](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/805/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like the question because it is clearly stated what is being asked and because it asks about the reasons of a phenomenon, not just about "what is correct".

Comment: I downvoted because even if the question is legit, the language is mixed and it would be better to provide two versions of the same question rather than asking mixed stuff.

Comment: @Alenanno What do you mean by "mixed stuff"?

Comment: @Olga Sorry, I didn't like how it came out but I didn't know how else to say it lol... I meant, one sentence in English and the next one in Russian. I know they are translations but it's not done as I have seen it's usually done (as a standard).

Comment: @Alenanno I simply overlooked the Russian sentences at the end of the post.

Comment: Good question. The Russian sentences mean pretty much the same. If an op wants to ask in both languages (to attract more answers), what standard shall we enforce?

Comment: I would suggest the following standard: a question is asked in one language, its translation is given below. The two are clearly separated from one another, all the examples are repeated in both original and in the translation parts.

Answer (score 2):

[What do "случайно" and "не случайно" mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/817/what-do-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be-and-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be-mean)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This one is ok but might use some additional context... I'll leave it like this for now.

Comment: pretty valid question to me

Comment: Good question, the motivation of the question is clear, there is enough context to understand what is reasonable to include in the answer. I an imagine that this is how the most of the future questions will look like.

Answer (score 1):

[Suffix mutation on стрелок to стрелка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/822/suffix-mutation-on-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-to-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I am still not sure whether the answer about fugitive vowels in suffixes is actually matching the question. It is not clear what is asked ("What is the correct case form?", "What why is there no vowel in the suffix?", something else?). Moreover, I think that if someone was looking for the fugitive vowel origin explanation, he would not be asking the same question.

Comment: @Olga Looks like he was asking why the case behaved differently, or at least it's my impression. The question could use some improvement.

Comment: Goog question from a non-native speaker, and a good answer too.

Answer (score 1):

[When and how "разбор полётов" became a idiom](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/826/when-and-how-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%91%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-became-a-idiom)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Too many questions. The last one should be removed. (I want to remove it now but I'll wait until the end of this evaluation.)

Comment: Too specific, in my opinion.

Comment: a good question, in my opinion. But I'd say that the op shouldn't refine nor update the question so that it becomes 3 separate questions.

Comment: @Alenanno, I agree with you, now I see that the last question is redundant. Though can not lie, I found this question very nice)))

Answer (score 1):

[Надменный и высокомерный](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/844/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It's always interesting to dig deeper into semantic differences between words. But I'm always sceptical when it turns out that two words are complete synonyms. I'd prefer to see more arguments in favor of such answer.

Comment: Nice question too. The lack of substantiation is a general problem for all our answers, of course, but the questions like this can lack source indeed (if none bothered to compare meanings of these two very words).

Answer (score 0):

[What case should a name use after the preposition 'with'?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/800/what-case-should-a-name-use-after-the-preposition-with)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is valid, but its title is misleading: "a name" can mean both "имя" and "название". The question is actually about family names.

Comment: Good question from a non-native speaker

Answer (score -1):

[Which one of these two pangram transliterations is correct?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/847/which-one-of-these-two-pangram-transliterations-is-correct)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It could use some detail and context in my opinion. Transliteration how? According to what system? There are at least 5 systems.

Comment: Transliteration questions are hardly on topic here. Unlike several other languages, it's not common to write Russian in Latin script without any speficic purpose, and the rules vary with the purpose.

Answer (score -4):

[Do these surnames imply anything?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/819/do-these-surnames-imply-anything)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this one... The question while on topic is certainly not the best one, I mean, it's not one of those questions that you know the OP really did that much effort, and if the effort was made, it wasn't shown in the question.

Comment: There are too many surnames, sounds like "do the name etymology research for me". We should encourage asking the questions like: "this source tells the name means this, this source tells that, which is right and why?"

Comment: I agree with @Quassnoi. A question is more like a list of questions of the same type that each need a separate answer. I guess that such questions tend to get lengthy answers and are hard to read.